# Metaprogramming predicate methods inside a Class - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, predicate

I have a class called `User`, which `has_many: roles, through: user_roles`. I am trying to metaprogram predicate methods for associated roles inside a user class like so:

```
class User < ActiverRecord::Base 
...      
  Role.all.pluck(:name).each do |role_name|
    define_method("#{role_name}?") do
      roles.map(&:name).include?(role_name)
    end
  end
...
end
```

While `Role.all.pluck(&:name)` does return an array of existing role names, the `define_method` never gets called, and my spec fails with undefined method:

```
  ...
  subject.roles << create(:role, name: 'foo')
  expect(subject.foo?).to be true #<= undefined method `foo?' for #<User...>
  ...
```

Comment: It should be `pluck(:name)` without the `&`. That may be throwing off the building of the collection, leading to `define_method` never being called.

Comment: @sixty4bit oops, updated. I decided to replace `.map` with `pluck` and forgot to remove `to_proc`. Still returns `undefined method` however

Comment: Ah ha. In that case, I think the answer may lie more fundamentally in how metaprogramming works. Your `Role.all...` logic is being executed when the `User` class is loaded, which is before the test is run. So the only methods that will be defined would be for roles that already existed before `User` was loaded. Creating the role in your test, after `User` has loaded, won't have any affect on that code that ran earlier. Hopefully that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metaprogramming technique you're employing is meant to take advantage of the fact that code just sitting inside of a class is going to be executed when the class is loaded. So when Rails loads your `User` class, *at that moment* the logic to define the predicate methods is being executed and methods are being created for whatever `Role.all` returns *at that moment when `User` is loaded*.

Creating a new role, as you do in the test, will therefore have no effect on what predicate methods were created when the class was loaded and the code was executed.

You can see this in action by creating a file called `count.rb` in any directory with the following code inside:

`$count += 1`

Then, open `irb` and type:

```
irb(main):001:0> $count = 0
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> require './count'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> $count
=> 1
```

Notice that `$count` was incremented by one when the file was loaded. Now, if you were to `require` the file again, nothing would happen. You could force the code to be re-loaded by using `load` instead of require:

```
# ...continued from above
irb(main):004:0> require './count'
=> false
irb(main):005:0> $count
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> load './foo.rb'
=> true
irb(main):007:0> $count
=> 2
```

So to get your test to pass, you would have to create the role, then force a reload of the `User` class, then make the assertion.

Comment: absolutely! ended up moving this test logic to a unit test for `Role` so that instantiating `User` occurs after new role is created.

Comment: Though this is an answer, that provides a working test, I would not go with this approach. That way adding new roles to the application will not have any effect unless cold restart / reload. I would define a callback on `Role#after_commit`, updating predicate methods in the `User` class.

Comment: To be clear: I wasn't trying to imply in my answer that this is an approach that should be implemented in the application code. I was just trying to explain *why* @Dimitry_N was having this problem in the test, to make sure that he understands how the underlying metaprogramming concept works, etc.